# XSLT sort with mixed childs

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
  <nodeLevel1>
    <nodeType1>node type 1</nodeType1>
    <nodeType2><rank>3</rank></nodeType2>
    <nodeType2><rank>1</rank></nodeType2>
    <nodeType2><rank>4</rank></nodeType2>
    <nodeType2><rank>2</rank></nodeType2>
    <nodeType3>node type 3</nodeType3>
  </nodeLevel1>
</root>
```

I sort this XML using the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" media-type="text/html"/>

      <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="nodeLevel1">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
              <xsl:sort select="rank" data-type="number" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <nodeLevel1>
    <nodeType1>node type 1</nodeType1>
    <nodeType3>node type 3</nodeType3>
    <nodeType2>
        <rank>1</rank>
    </nodeType2>
    <nodeType2>
        <rank>2</rank>
    </nodeType2>
    <nodeType2>
        <rank>3</rank>
    </nodeType2>
    <nodeType2>
        <rank>4</rank>
    </nodeType2>
</nodeLevel1>
</root>
```

The problem is that all "nodeType2" are not at the correct position in my XML.
How can I do to keep the nodes "nodeType1" before "nodeType2" and the nodes "nodeType3" after "nodeType2". (The solution must not use the element name "nodeType1" or "nodeType3" because it can be renamed to anything)

So, the result shoud be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <nodeLevel1>
    <nodeType1>node type 1</nodeType1>
    <nodeType2>
        <rank>1</rank>
    </nodeType2>
    <nodeType2>
        <rank>2</rank>
    </nodeType2>
    <nodeType2>
        <rank>3</rank>
    </nodeType2>
    <nodeType2>
        <rank>4</rank>
    </nodeType2>
    <nodeType3>node type 3</nodeType3>
</nodeLevel1>
</root>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is have a template that matches the first **nodeType2** element

```
<xsl:template match="nodeType2[1]">
```

And within this, you select and sort all the nodeType2 elements

```
<xsl:for-each select="self::*|following-sibling::nodeType2">
   <xsl:sort select="rank" data-type="number" />
    <!-- Copy element -->
    <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
 </xsl:for-each>
```

The only other thing you would need is another template to stop the other **nodeType2** elements being output twice

```
<xsl:template match="nodeType2" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" media-type="text/html"/>

      <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="nodeType2[1]">
          <xsl:for-each select="self::*|following-sibling::nodeType2">
              <xsl:sort select="rank" data-type="number" />
              <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
            </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="nodeType2" />
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<root>
   <nodeLevel1>
      <nodeType1>node type 1</nodeType1>
      <nodeType2>
         <rank>1</rank>
      </nodeType2>
      <nodeType2>
         <rank>2</rank>
      </nodeType2>
      <nodeType2>
         <rank>3</rank>
      </nodeType2>
      <nodeType2>
         <rank>4</rank>
      </nodeType2>
      <nodeType3>node type 3</nodeType3>
   </nodeLevel1>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation works with any element names (no name is hardcoded) and is efficient as it uses keys to identify the groups**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kSameNamed" match="nodeLevel1/*" use=
  "generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="nodeLevel1">
  <nodeLevel1>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "*[not(name() = name(preceding-sibling::*[1]))]"/>
  </nodeLevel1>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="nodeLevel1/*">
  <xsl:for-each select="key('kSameNamed', generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[1]))">
   <xsl:sort select="rank" data-type="number"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
  <nodeLevel1>
    <nodeType1>node type 1</nodeType1>
    <nodeType2><rank>3</rank></nodeType2>
    <nodeType2><rank>1</rank></nodeType2>
    <nodeType2><rank>4</rank></nodeType2>
    <nodeType2><rank>2</rank></nodeType2>
    <nodeType3>node type 3</nodeType3>
  </nodeLevel1>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
   <nodeLevel1>
      <nodeType1>node type 1</nodeType1>
      <nodeType2>
         <rank>1</rank>
      </nodeType2>
      <nodeType2>
         <rank>2</rank>
      </nodeType2>
      <nodeType2>
         <rank>3</rank>
      </nodeType2>
      <nodeType2>
         <rank>4</rank>
      </nodeType2>
      <nodeType3>node type 3</nodeType3>
   </nodeLevel1>
</root>
```

**If we now apply the same transformation to a completely different XML document:**

```
<r>
  <nodeLevel1>
    <X1>node type 1</X1>
    <Y2><rank>3</rank></Y2>
    <Y2><rank>1</rank></Y2>
    <Y2><rank>4</rank></Y2>
    <Y2><rank>2</rank></Y2>
    <Z3>node type 3</Z3>
    <A4><rank>8</rank></A4>
    <A4><rank>2</rank></A4>
    <A4><rank>9</rank></A4>
    <A4><rank>3</rank></A4>
    <B5><rank>8</rank></B5>
    <B5><rank>2</rank></B5>
    <B5><rank>9</rank></B5>
    <B5><rank>3</rank></B5>
    <C7>Node of Type C7</C7>
  </nodeLevel1>
</r>
```

**we again get the correct result:**

```
<r>
   <nodeLevel1>
      <X1>node type 1</X1>
      <Y2>
         <rank>1</rank>
      </Y2>
      <Y2>
         <rank>2</rank>
      </Y2>
      <Y2>
         <rank>3</rank>
      </Y2>
      <Y2>
         <rank>4</rank>
      </Y2>
      <Z3>node type 3</Z3>
      <A4>
         <rank>2</rank>
      </A4>
      <A4>
         <rank>3</rank>
      </A4>
      <A4>
         <rank>8</rank>
      </A4>
      <A4>
         <rank>9</rank>
      </A4>
      <B5>
         <rank>2</rank>
      </B5>
      <B5>
         <rank>3</rank>
      </B5>
      <B5>
         <rank>8</rank>
      </B5>
      <B5>
         <rank>9</rank>
      </B5>
      <C7>Node of Type C7</C7>
   </nodeLevel1>
</r>
```